Do i need to pay to my ISP every digital asset someone download from my server?
I have searched a lot and haven't found a concrete answer on the subject, i want to build a personal webpage and upload there my digital work (projects), that being games, game assets, software tools you name it.
I would like to treat it as a personal repository sort of thing and have a great deal of them being available to other people either free or with some donation for some of them via a download button (obviously)
.
Someone said to me
"you cannot do it! its not worth it!"
-why not lol?
"because of the bandwidth you would have to pay to sustain all those individual downloads"
-um wtf you mean?
"you need to pay additional money to your ISP provider for every Gigabyte etc someone download from your site man, say someone download 10GB from your server for those 10GB you will have to pay say 1$ multiply that by 1k, plus you need to upload a lot copies of those files to be available to the public so your bandwidth price can be calculated"
-this cant be accurate you're misunderstanding things.
what really bugged me the most aside the pay extra deal was the "have multiple copies"...
So here i am thinking to my self, ill just make a download button and the server is gonna just copy the files and send them to the client, why pay for a simple function such as that?
especially when i can do it on my own? like you're buying some sort of potatoes in kilograms?? So im asking, back between 90s-20s things were that simple, has anything changed since then? am i getting something wrong? do i really have to pay the bandwidth in kilograms? do i need to really copy say a game asset or a blender model or a movie and copy it 100 times and upload it on my server?? this cant be right right? what am i missing here?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You might have to check your contract or ask your ISP how much traffic is included and what you might have to pay. Some ISPs have a not exactly defined "fair use" condition.

The person who spoke to you does not seem to understand what you want to do.
When you use your own internet connection, you don't need to pay any extra's when you setup a server and let other people connect to it and use it.
Yes, they will use up bandwidth, but your connection comes with bandwidth already. As long as the amount of bandwidth is not enormous, you are likely not going to have any issues here.
Do note, of a massive amount of people try to download something at the same time, the simultaneous amount of traffic will clog up your entire upstream and as such, your internet will slow down up to the point that you can't use your own internet eithr. Those who browse your website will find it very slow too.
A sidenote is that your ISP may have a fair-use policy for bandwidth, in which case, they may disconnect your internet if they find it to be too much. This is when you have more than 50.000 users/bots connecting at the same time.
Also, when you have a server at a datacenter, like most websites, those servers are connected to a much, much faster internet. As a result, when people connect to your webserver, even when no one else is browsing it, they'll find that its a bit of a slow website.
But if you choose to host your site at rented webspace, then you may get things like cost for bandwidth, diskspace, etc.
It really is going to boil down to this:
How large is your project and how many visitors do you think you'll get? For a small project (say, 100 people max), hosting from home is not going to be a problem, but if this grows into something big, at some point you will run into problems and may have to migrate to shared webhosting or better anyway.
Lastly, note that it is illegal to host anything you did not make, so if your idea is to create a website and host programs, games, images, etc that you did not make, your ISP can disconnect your internet entirely for breaching their terms of service.

I also feel like this is a bit of a how long is a piece of string problem - there's hosting options that are pay by space, pay by bandwidth, or a semi flat rate. It very much depends on what OP opts for. how big the files are and what the specific holding uses as a metric for billing.

No its gonna be my work and my wife's mainly, that was an example, i didn't get the part of make a lot individual copies of the same file and upload them on the server, i have game assets i want to maybe try and sell, i just dont want to co-operate with the new  epic games unreal asset game store that is merged nowdays into fab because there is no organize and instead of going to itchio, i thought to share some of my friends projects as well on my own site.

You just upload it once. What they were talking about, is that every time someone downloads your file, they will make a copy of that file themselves, and that means each download uses bandwidth.
